# Steam url api inserting variables

Tags: php, json

I have been attempting to use steam api to display a persons name.  When I insert there steamid in directly it works however, when I try to use a variable it doesn't work.  The thing that confuses me is that I have this exact same code for my queue that works however this does not work.  I have looked around and I believe I am doing this right but for some reason it is not working.  Any help here would be great.  Thanks.

```
<?
$name = 76xxxxxxxxxxx;
$response = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?    key=xxx&steamids={$name}&format=json";
$middle = (file_get_contents($response));
$json = json_decode($middle, true);
$b = $json['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
print_r($b);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$name` variable needs to be wrapped in quotes.

```
$name = "76xxxxxxxxxxx";
```

This will properly create your `response` variable

Comment: Thanks.  So I added this to my code. $rname = "\"$name\"";  and changed $name to $rname in the api but it is still not working.  Any ideas?  When I echo it the $rname is in quotes so I can't see why it is not working in the api.

Comment: Why are you escaping your quotes? Just wrap the profile I'd number in quotes so that it is a string not a 64bit integer.

Comment: Well in my actual code I am getting the steam ids by mysql and looping through them using the while loop to display there steam name.

Comment: At the end of your while loop you should end up with a string that looks like `$name = "76xxxxxxxxxxx1,76xxxxxxxxxxx2,76xxxxxxxxxxx3,76xxxxxxxxxxx4"`. Again, only two sets of quotes, nothing escaped. Pass that single string to the API to get a response with all 4 (up to 100 at a time) players.

Comment: So it still isn't working. Here is what I get for one loop when I print the $response: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=xxx&steamids= 76xxx &format=json      When I var_dump the $json I don't get any of the player data.  Could the problem be the spaces before and after the steamid?

Comment: The white spaces were the problem.  I just stripped them to fix it, thanks for the help!